# JdbcPollingChannelAdapter polling messages dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

My application has the following input channel adapter:

```
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "databaseInputChannel")
    public JdbcPollingChannelAdapter checkDbForInput() {
        JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSource(), "select * from users");
        adapter.setUpdateSql("update users set load_status = '3' where id in (:id)");
        adapter.setMaxRows(100);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow pollingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("databaseInputChannel")
                .split()
                .channel("databaseRowInputChannel")
                .get();
    }

    @Async
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "databaseRowInputChannel")
    public void processMessage(Message<?> message) {
    }
```

How do I get the poller to just poll the next 100 rows when the previous 100 are processed (limited by the thread pool)?

I tried to use jdbcPollingChannelAdapter.setTrigger or jdbcPollingChannelAdapter.setTaskDecorator as suggested on some places. But it looks like these have been removed in spring 6. On the other hand I think there should be an easier way to achieve the wanted behaviour.

Comment: It feels like you are trying to do a task which Spring Batch is designed for with Spring Integration.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did a short research and you are right spring batch could also used for such a task. But according to this statement spring integration is better suited:
"In summary, Spring Integration is a better fit for the use case of reading data from a database and publishing it to a RabbitMQ queue due to its support for integration with databases and message brokers."

Comment: Where are you publishing? I see a process message so it just seems you are only using RabbitMQ as a means to couple tasks.

Comment: I left away the publishing part to get a simple use case for my problem.

Comment: Spring Batch does have a writer for rabbitmq. However I do not really understand the issue you currently have, it will poll 100 messages, as soon as they are on the channel it will continue with the next, it isn't aware of the further handling of the messages.

Comment: That is unfortunately not the case. I added  a Thread.sleep to the processMessage. After the first poll my 10 threads are "busy". The poller still polls and updates the records in the background. All my 1000 rows are updated to load_status = 3 while the threads still processing the first 10 messages.

Comment: Which is exactly what I stated would happen, the poller puts them on the channel and proceeds.

Comment: But I like to have it such as it takes the next 100 when the first 100 are processed :-)

Comment: That is not how this works. It polls puts stuff on a channel and continues, that is its job. For what you want, Spring Batch seems more suitable. Or update as part of the processing (although that might be slower).

Answer (score 1):

There never was a `setTrigger` nor `setTaskDecorator` in the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`. You are missing the fact that `@InboundChannelAdapter` is a pollable channel adapter based on a scheduled task. By default it is done per second. The next polling cycle is started after one second of the previous is finished.

See the `poller` attribute of that `@InboundChannelAdapter`. This is the place where you can adjust polling cycle and threading.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#configuration-using-poller-annotation

Comment: You are right the poller works as it should. My problem is the @Async, it hands all messages to the taskExecutor (queuing the threads) and goes on polling.

I'm currently experimenting with ExecutorChannel and an own TaskExecutor with queueCapacity = 0. That seems to work so far but I assume there is an easier solution around.

Comment: There is a `fixedRate` option for the poller to schedule a new task while the current one is still in progress

Answer (score 0):

So far the best way to limit the input is using a poller advice.

This pauses the poller once the thread queue is bigger than two times the core threads:

```
public class ThreadQueueAwareReceiveMessageAdvice implements ReceiveMessageAdvice {
    private final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;
    private int maxThreadQueue;

    public ThreadQueueAwareReceiveMessageAdvice(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
        this.maxThreadQueue = 2 * taskExecutor.getCorePoolSize();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean beforeReceive(Object source) {
        if (taskExecutor.getQueueSize() >= maxThreadQueue) {
            return false;
        }
        return ReceiveMessageAdvice.super.beforeReceive(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, Object source) {
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is the poller using the advice:

```
    @Bean
    public PollerMetadata dbPoller() {
        return Pollers
                .fixedRate(500)
                .maxMessagesPerPoll(10)
                .advice(new ThreadQueueAwareReceiveMessageAdvice(taskExecutor))
                .get();
    }
```